# XML > PHP only in source code

Tags: php, xml

I have a slight issue whereby the API I'm using for part of my service uses a rsp stat to handle the success / error messages in XML.

So we use a form to post it data and it returns the data like the following example:

```
<rsp stat="ok"> 
    <success msg="accepted" transactionid="505eeb9c43969d4919c0a6b3f7a4dfbb" messageid="a92eff8d65cf48e9c6e96702a7b07400"/> 
</rsp>
```

The following is most of the script used :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
     // ToDo: Replace the placeholders in brackets with your data.
     // For example - curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UsERPWD, 'SMSUser:PassW0rD#');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
print "ERROR ". curl_error($ch) ."\n
";
} 
curl_close($ch); 
print_r($xml);
```

The only problem is that when it is parsed and displayed via the print_r command , it only displays via source code for some strange reason and we have no idea how to display it via the page

Basically we would like a system whereby if rsp stat="ok" then "Sent" else "unsent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a simple way could be:

```
if (strpos($xml, 'stat="ok"') !== false) {
    echo "sent";
} else {
    echo "unsent";
}
```

http://codepad.org/pkzsfsMk

This would replace `print($xml);`.

Comment: if((@DOMDocument::loadHTML($xml))->getElementsByTagName("rsp")->item(0)->getAttribute("stat")==='ok'){echo 'sent';}else{echo 'unsent';throw new \RuntimException('unexpected stat response: '.(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($xml))->getElementsByTagName("rsp")->item(0)->getAttribute("stat"));}

Answer (score 0):

Put that code in a function, and have the function return your $xml.

Assuming you had a function called getRspStat() you could just do like:

```
      echo getRspStat();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like that:

(see also on [CodePad.org](http://codepad.org/fccWChNV))

```
function xmlRequestWasSuccessful($xml) {
    $result = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $result = (string)$result['stat'];
    if ($result == 'ok') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$xml = '<rsp stat="ok">
<success msg="accepted" transactionid="505eeb9c43969d4919c0a6b3f7a4dfbb" messageid="a92eff8d65cf48e9c6e96702a7b07400"/>
</rsp>';

$stat = xmlRequestWasSuccessful($xml);
```

you will receive 'true' boolean in the result (`$stat` variable). Adapt it to support the case when there is an error. Since no details on how it looks when error occurs, this is how you can do it now:

```
if ($stat) {
    // do something on success ('sent' something)
} else {
    // do something on success (display 'unsent' message for example)
}
```